# mysql select sort by day and time str_to_date

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table as
Table: orders

```
Order | day                 | time
1     | Tuesday 31-10-2017  | 10:00 AM
2     | Thursday 02-11-2017 | 11:00 AM
3     | Tuesday 31-10-2017  | 01:00 PM
4     | Tuesday 31-10-2017  | 10:00 AM
5     | Sunday 29-10-2017   | 09:30 AM
```

I need to sort orders based on day and time , for example:

```
Order | day                 | time
5     | Sunday 29-10-2017   | 09:30 AM
1     | Tuesday 31-10-2017  | 10:00 AM
4     | Tuesday 31-10-2017  | 10:30 AM
3     | Tuesday 31-10-2017  | 01:00 PM
2     | Thursday 02-11-2017 | 11:00 AM
```

tried:

```
select * from request ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(time,'%h:%i%p') asc, STR_TO_DATE(day,'%l %d-%m-%Y') desc
```

but thats not sorting as expected...

Comment: Why using this kind of data-type while timestamp can do this without any custom query?

Comment: timezone Africa/Cairo

Answer (score 2):

Really, you should store dates using internal date formats, not as a string.  You can readily get the date of the week using date/time functions.

Your date format makes this even harder, but you can do:

```
order by str_to_date(substring_index(day, ' ', -1), '%d-%m-%Y'),
         str_to_date(time,'%h:%i%p')
```

Now that you've fixed this problem, go back to your data and do:

```
alter table orders add column orderdate datetime;

update orders
    set orderdate = addtime(str_to_date(substring_index(day, ' ', -1), '%d-%m-%Y'),
                            str_to_date(time,'%h:%i%p'));
```

Check that `orderdate` is correct.  Then do:

```
alter table orders drop column day;
alter table orders drop column time;
```

Isn't that nice?  Your data is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Following query will work:

```
select * from request 
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(day,' ',-1),'%d-%m-%Y'),
         STR_TO_DATE(time,'%h:%i%p') desc,
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should order the more important column first. So the order of the order statements should be;

```
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(day,'%l %d-%m-%Y') desc, STR_TO_DATE(time,'%h:%i%p') asc
```

And the day column should be ordered asc, not desc;

```
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(day,'%l %d-%m-%Y') asc, STR_TO_DATE(time,'%h:%i%p') asc
```

By the way, I think [the pattern](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) of the day of the week should be `%W` instead of `%l`;

```
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(day,'%W %d-%m-%Y') asc, STR_TO_DATE(time,'%h:%i%p') asc
```

I tried here;
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8fdbf/11/0